# Scroll event is not firing on my div element

Tags: jquery

I want to track a scroll of a div, but it does not work. What is wrong?

```
$('#box').on('scroll', function(){
    alert(33);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n5yaeLyv/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the `#box` element is not being scrolled in your example - the `window` is. By default block elements will expand to fit their contents. To stop this behaviour and allow the element to scroll you need to set its `height` and `overflow` properties:

```
#box {
    height: 100px; /* amend this as required */
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n5yaeLyv/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You should add a height and overflow property to your div to make 'scroll' event work.

```
#box {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 200px;
}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/alekskorovin/j5ax9vm6/)